# Pyspark Dataframe to AWS MySql: requirement failed: The driver could not open a JDBC connection

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-rds, mysql-connector, spark-jdbc

I want to write a pyspark dataframe into a MySQL table in AWS RDS, but I keep getting the error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The driver could not open a JDBC connection. Check the URL: jdbc:mysql:mtestdb.ch4i3d3jc0yc.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

My code looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

spark = SparkSession.builder\
            .appName('test-app')\
            .config('spark.jars.packages', 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28')\
            .getOrCreate()

properties = {'user':'admin', 'password':'password', 'driver':'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'}
resultDF.write.jdbc(url='jdbc:mysql:mtestdb.ch4i3d3jc0yc.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com', table='mcm_objects', properties=properties)\
            .mode('append')\
            .save()
```

I also tried the url 'jdbc:mysql://mtestdb.ch4i3d3jc0yc.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
but then I get the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
```

No idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` should be `{dbName}.{dbtable}`:

```
resultDF.write.jdbc(url='jdbc:mysql:mtestdb.ch4i3d3jc0yc.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com', table='{dbname}.mcm_objects', properties=properties)\
            .mode('append')\
            .save()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This solves my problem, but now I am getting the error message 
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Table or view 'bulistats.mcm_objects' already exists. SaveMode: ErrorIfExists    

Even when I change the mode to overwrite

Comment: Ah I got it. Adding the mode inside the jdbc() does the job. Thanks a lot again